# How to deploy Angular app in .NET Core project on Github

Tags: angular, visual-studio, github, repository

Created a project using the ASP.NET Core 5 + Angular template. The ClientApp folder that the studio generates automatically when creating such a project was deleted. I created an Angular-10 project separately in Visual Code via CLI and inserted it instead of the ClientApp folder into the project. Everything works, building good and started well. This is what the project looks like(ignore the locks and the plus sign in front of the Angular application folder for now).

Solution view:

[image: 1]

Now I want to create a private repository on GitHub and upload the project. (Visual Studio 2019 Preview)
I open a window through Visual Studio where I specify my username and password, tick the private box and click Push to GitHub.

Connect to GitHub window:

[image: 2]

As a result, I see locks in front of each item and a + sign in front of the Angular app folder.

In general, it already has a "+" sign, which means I added it, at least I thought it should appear in changes, but there are no any changes in Changes Team Explorer. Then I tried to change something inside the Angular application (I created a class in the .scss file) and one change appeared in Changes Team Ex. This is how it looks.

Sub module:

[image: 3]

As a result, I can't committing it and actually do something with it. How can I organize work fully with a project include angular folder in my private repository, which as I understand it is given for one account for free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the .git folder and the gitignore file from the ClientApp repo. Then you should see the folder under changes in the Team Explorer window of Visual Studio. I think VS was "confused" because the project contained two git repos - one for the entire project and then a second one in the Angular Clientapp directory. I was just having this same issue and this is what worked for me so I hope it helps!